# Understand the sorting of a vector of pair (int and pointer to object)

Tags: c++, sorting, std-pair

I have a vector of pair defined as follows:

```
vector<pair<int, myClass *>> myVector;
```

The vector is sorted using the following:

```
sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
```

This code is not mine and everything is working fine.

The only thing I don't get and I would like to understand is:

When I have two elements of my vector with the same int value as first, how the sorting is done? On which criteria?

I was thinking first, it's based on the value of the pointer to my object in the pair. But I can't see it.

I want to understand it because I need to reproduce this behavior (the sorting) on a demonstrator on Matlab.

Comment: The answer is in the manual, as it often happens [operator==,!=,<,<=,>,>=,<=>(std::pair)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp).

Comment: Take a look at how `std::pair::operator<` is defined.

Comment: Pointers to two independently created objects are not comparable, and even if the implementation can compare them the result is meaningless - you have (usually) no control over the allocation. So you may assume the items with equal first component are ordered randomly.

Comment: Thaks for your answer. I looked at it but still can't figure it out.
My second is an object with mutliple properties (vector of other objects, structures, iterator, boolean).

For the sorted elements with the same int, I checked every values of the second and can't find a logic.

Comment: @CiaPan: The process is repetitive and the items with equal first are always ordered the same. But I can't find a pattern.

Comment: Check the numeric values of pointers to those objects. Those are second components of pairs in your vector. As others already said they are compared when first components are equal.

Comment: Hi, so you're right. It's indeed the numeric value of the pointer which is use as second sorting argument.
This behavior doesn't make any sense in the program itself (once again, not my program) but also it won't be reproducible in Matlab.
Anyway, thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment to my question, tt's indeed the numeric value of the pointer which is use as second sorting argument. This behavior doesn't make any sense in the program itself (once again, not my program) but also it won't be reproducible in Matlab. Anyway, thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` uses `std::less` as default comparator. For a `std::pair` that just calls the elements `operator<` and sorts with respect to `first`, then `second`. For details see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp.

However, comparing pointers that are not pointing to elements of the same array via `<` is implementation defined. You need to use `std::less` for proper comparison of pointers in general.

Hence, the order of elements with same `first` is implementation defined and difficult to be reproduced exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
sort(A.begin(), A.end(), 
[]( pair<int, myClass *> p1, pair<int, myClass *>p2 )  
{ return p1.first < p2.first; });
```

modify the lambda according your wish or how you want the sorting to happen.